# packaged wearable app not getting installed using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, wear-os

I have developed wearable only app for Android.Now,to get it installed on wearable i need to first put in handheld(as per process)

**Note: I am using eclipse for development.**

For that i have created respective Handheld project for the same purpose.
I have exported signed .apk for wearable app say wearable_app.apk & copied it to res/raw folder of handheld app.
Created wearablde_desc.xml in res/xml folder of Handheld project

Wearable_desc.xml:

```
<wearableApp package="com.example.com">
     <versionName>1.0</versionName>
     <versionCode>1</versionCode>
     <rawPathResId>wearable_app</rawPathResId>
</wearableApp>
```

where wearable_app is the .apk file i have put up in raw folder of Handheld app.

I have also added following lines to AndroidManifest.xml file of handheld project

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.wearable.beta.app"
               android:resource="@xml/wearable_app_desc"/>
```

But still my app is not get pushed/installed on Android wear.Can anyone out here please help me point out what i might be missing in the process?

Comment: Make sure you follow the documentation steps here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html ... also, make sure that you check the adb logcat output for anything involving WearablePkgInstaller, which might tell you what is wrong with your application. Also, make sure the permissions you request on the wearable are a subset of the phone application.

Comment: Hi Wayne i am using eclipse to get it done whereas documentation on developer.android.com explains in terms of Android Studio.And there  is no such specific permission my wearable app is using which i should be entering into my handheld one.If you could help in any other way that would be really helpful..

Comment: What did adb logcat | grep WearablePkgInstaller on both wearable and phone show?

Comment: Hi wayne don't know but adding following meta-data tag in my wearable app manifest file worked out in my case: <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>.Previously i have added this meta-data tag only in companion handheld app.Still i am not able to find out the reason behind this..Anyways thanks for your help. :)

Comment: This makes sense. When using Google Play Services you need to have this present as well.